# TPL doesn’t appear to improve execution speed in MSDN example

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool

When I use [the example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399.aspx):

```
var queryA = from num in numberList.AsParallel()
             select ExpensiveFunction(num); //good for PLINQ

var queryB = from num in numberList.AsParallel()
             where num % 2 > 0
             select num; //not as good for PLINQ
```

My example program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);

        var numberList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            numberList.Add(i);
        }
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var queryA = from num in numberList
                     select ExpensiveFunction(num); //good for PLINQ
        var c = queryA.ToList<int>();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        var queryB = from num in numberList.AsParallel()
                     select ExpensiveFunction(num); //good for PLINQ
        c = queryB.ToList<int>();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
}

static int ExpensiveFunction(int a)
{
    a = a + 100 - 9 + 0 + 98;
    // Console.WriteLine(a);
    return a;
}
```

The result is:

```
7
41
```

Why is using `AsParallel()` slower than not using it?

Comment: `a += 189;` is **NOT** expensive to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ExpensiveFunction` really isn't an expensive function for a computer.

Simple maths can be done extremely fast.

Perhaps try `Thread.Sleep(500);` instead. This will tell the CPU to pause for half a second which will simulate the effect of an actual expensive function.

***Edit*** — I should state, the reason it is slower is because of the overhead parallel processing involves is more work than the actual calculation. [See this answer for a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418495/88588).

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. Hi. I understanded. Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: @user2532263 check out http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/SampleLibraries.aspx "Asynchrony in C# 5" provides some great practical examples of parallel programming in C#.