# c# Parallel vs Sequential

Tags: c#, optimization, parallel-processing, sequential

I got a large list to loop through (1.500.000 items), with each item I have to do a very small check. Totally during 30 seconds.

The CPU utilization when using Sequential is around 10%, so there's a lot of resources not used.

The first thought was to use Parallel, but due to the limited time duration for each item, Parallel lasts longer than a sequential Foreach, this is due to "[Why was the parallel version slower than the sequential version in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418493/why-was-the-parallel-version-slower-than-the-sequential-version-in-this-example)", which explains that the creation of each task will cost time.

So I had another thought and that is to divide the list in 4 (or more) equal peaces and create a thread to loop through the items to get it faster.

Before creating my own class, is this a good approach? Or any other thoughts of how to speed things up? Or do you know a better way of handling this.

### Code

The code I created for another parallel approach: (used in my own static class)

```
public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> body, int listDevide)
{
    // Number of items
    int items = list.Count();
    // Divided (in int, so floored)
    int listPart = items / listDevide;
    // Get numbers extra for last run
    int rest = items % listDevide;

    // List to save the actions
    var actions = new List<Action>();
    for(var x = 0; x < listDevide; x++)
    {
        // Create the actions
        actions.Add(delegate {
            foreach(var item in list.Skip(x * listPart).Take(listPart))
            {
                body.Invoke(item);
            }
        });
    }

    // Run the actions parallel
    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
}
```

Remark: "rest" variable to do the last items is currently not used in this example.

Solution below, more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx

Comment: MAke it two threads and see is the cpu goes to 20% ...

Comment: What did you get by using second approach? better performance?

Comment: When the time to calculate 1 item is very low, it's better to use the partitioner, to process the list in small portions per thread. Using only parallel it would cost me more time than using a sequential loop. Using the partitioner there is a performance gain (it's faster than the sequential loop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, partitioning the input array is a good approach.

In fact, Microsoft provide a [`Partitioner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768.aspx) class to help with exactly this approach.

Here's an example showing how to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            double sum = 0;
            Func<double, double> func = x => Math.Sqrt(Math.Sin(x));
            object locker = new object();

            double[] data = testData();

            // For each double in data[] we are going to calculate Math.Sqrt(Math.Sin(x)) and
            // add all the results together.
            //
            // To do this, we use class Partitioner to split the input array into just a few partitions,
            // (the Partitioner will use knowledge about the number of processor cores to optimize this)
            // and then add up all the values using a separate thread for each partition.
            //
            // We use threadLocalState to compute the total for each partition, and then we have to
            // add all these together to get the final sum. We must lock the additon because it isn't
            // threadsafe, and several threads could be doing it at the same time.

            Parallel.ForEach
            (
                Partitioner.Create(0, data.Length),

                () => 0.0,

                (subRange, loopState, threadLocalState) =>
                {
                    for (int i = subRange.Item1; i < subRange.Item2; i++)
                    {
                        threadLocalState += func(data[i]);
                    }

                    return threadLocalState;
                },

                finalThreadLocalState =>
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        sum += finalThreadLocalState;
                    }
                }
            );

            Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + sum);
        }

        private static double[] testData()
        {
            double[] array = new double[1000003]; // Test with an odd number of values.

            Random rng = new Random(12345);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
                array[i] = rng.Next() & 3; // Don't want large values for this simple test.

            return array;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```