# performance assessment of a lambda expression in a foreAch loop in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code in my program:
This code will iterate through hundreds of thousands of records and i therefore need to look to see if it can be improved:

```
private void FillObjectTypes(Type type, ElementMapping mapping )
        {
            foreach (var fieldMapping in mapping.FieldMappings.Values.Where(mpng => mpng.ConversionType == ConversionType.InferFromPropertyType))
            {
                fieldMapping.PropertyType = ReflectionUtils.GetPropertyType(type, fieldMapping.PropertyName);
            }
            mapping.FieldMappingsTypesSet = true;
        }
```

Any idea to an improvement of the code will be highly appreciated. My main question being how the lambda expression will affect performance.

And the code for the reflection below:

```
public static Type GetPropertyType(Type objectType, string propertyName)
        {
            CheckCache(objectType);
            try
            {
                return propertiesByType[objectType][propertyName].PropertyType;
            }
            catch(KeyNotFoundException excp)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Failed to find property:'{propertyName}' in object type:'{objectType.Name}'",excp);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're using refection in each loop? That is not effective.

Comment: @PoulBak: this is the kind of comment i was looking for. I will change that

Comment: Use parallel foreach - check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17486002

Answer (score 1):

Your Lambda expression here is just doing filtering  so I cannot think of optimization for this `Where` clause.

As I have seen some suggestions of using parallel loops I would like to point out that **Parallel code is not always faster than the sequential one.**  And that is because of the extra overhead in creating and synchronizing multiple threads.

I guess that **a parallel loop in your example would be slower than a normal sequential one**, because the work done in each loop is minimal.

See [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/parallel-foreach-vs-foreach-loop-in-C-Sharp/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418493/why-was-the-parallel-version-slower-than-the-sequential-version-in-this-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use [task parallel library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) to evaluate in parallel

```
mapping.FieldMappings.Values
    .AsParallel()
    .Where( ... )
    .ForAll( fieldMapping =>
    {
        fieldMapping.PropertyType = ReflectionUntils.GetPropertyType( type, fieldMapping.PropertyName );
    } );
```